# Problems with deleting selected files

Tags: matlab, indexing

I want to delete all files that start with letter `'f'` in a folder. This is what I've tried:

```
delete (fullfile(datapath,folder_name),sprintf('^%s.*\.nii$','f'));
```

For some reason when I do this, I get the error that `\.` isn't a valid control character and also it thinks that I want to delete the entire directory. Could anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you tell if it's complaining about the first or the second '.'? It looks like you escaped one of them but maybe you need to escape the first one as well to match on a literal '.' in the folder name too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) is primarily aimed at formatting data into a string format and doesn't work with RegEx expressions.  However, [`delete`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delete.html)'s wildcard `*` should suffice here according to [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delete.html#f71-847401):

```
delete(fullfile(datapath,folder_name,'f*.nii'));
```

Comment: Thanks. Earlier I tried almost the same line but with ) after folder_name and that didn't work.

Comment: @A.Rainer You may not have concatenated the string since the posted snippet shows two arguments being passed to `delete` not a single string.  `delete([fullfile(datapath,folder_name),filesep,'f*.nii']);` is the same as above.